# How do I select the text of the xpath class within the class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

How do I get text values for "a-offscreen" class?

This is sample working code to test

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=ipad&ref=nb_sb_noss'
driver.get(url)
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//h2/a').text.strip()
# price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "a- 
offscreen")]').text  # does not work
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "a-price- 
whole")]').text  # work
print('title::', title)
print('price::', price)
```

This is xml I am working..
[image]

I'd like to get the price text value using "xpath" -> $299.00

This is the code I'm trying to do.

```
price = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "a-offscreen")]').text
```

I can't get any value.

However, when I tried different pricing text in the "class",
[image]

```
 price = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "a-price-whole")]').text
```

it works(get price)

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Booboo Sorry, I add my test sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "a-offscreen")]').text
```

to

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "a-offscreen")]').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can I ask you why you use .get_attribute("innerHTML")inner in this case not ".text"?

Comment: They have hidden html elements, which render in browser and hide then. So when you try to get `text` - browser can not find it in hidden html, but `innerHTML` - return full object with html elements.